# What is the VP in a subject-dependent inversion?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

A canonical declarative clause consists of a subject and a predicate, the former normally being a noun phrase (NP) and the latter mostly a verb phrase (VP). Therefore, a canonical declarative clause is divided into two large chunks: NP + VP.

In a subject-dependent inversion, on the other hand, the clause has the construction of 'dependent + verb + subject' as in:

> Under the table lies a dog.

Where 'under the table' is the dependent, 'lies' is the verb, and 'a dog' is the subject.

Now, is this inverted sentence also divided into two large chunks? If so, what is the VP in this case? Is it 'Under the table lies' as follows?

> Under the table lies (VP) + a dog (NP)

Or should this sentence be divided differently with a different VP?

Comment: I'm curious why you think this type of inversion would change anything. The dog is still under the table no matter what.

Comment: @KarlG I'm not asking about semantics, I'm asking about syntax. Why would you think the same semantics would lead to the same syntax?

Comment: The inversion does not change the syntax. The NP "a dog" is subject, and the VP "under the table lies" is predicate.

Comment: @BillJ Hmmm. Ok, but to underline JK2's point, what is the  VP in *Is he happy?*

Comment: @Araucaria Please see my answer below with tree, which should answer your question .

Comment: So, does, "A dog - lies - under the table." alter the sentence completely? Or am I complicating this example?

Comment: Why does "Is he happy" even related to "Does he lie [under the table]? Apart from that, this could be construed as a joke: He  might be lying elsewhere, too.

Answer (score 2):

> *Under the table lies a dog.*

Here's a suggested simplified tree:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the requested tree diagram. But it's just unfathomable to me how a subject alone without any predicate can constitute a clause.

Comment: But it has a predicate represented by the two GAPs, which are anaphoric to "lies" + "under the table". So the predicate is "lies under the table". That's how gapping works.

Answer (score -1):

Araucaria asked about the VP in the clause "Is he happy?"

Here is a tree diagram showing how the elements in a simple non-canonical clause are diagrammed. Note the functions label of 'prenucleus' for the verb which is co-indexed to the predicator function represented by 'gap':

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason that you've drawn a tree diagram of 'Is he happy?', about which @Araucaria asked about in a comment, in an answer to my question? I'm all for tree diagrams, so I'd like you to add one for my question (_Under the table lies a dog._). Could you please?

Comment: @JK2 I could, but the idea was to give you a clue about how clauses with inversion are analysed. Suppose you apply what I've demonstrated to your particular example, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Could you transfer your answer on Araucaria's post and delete it here?

Comment: @BillJ All inversions are not created equal. Your diagram is about subject-auxiliary inversion, which is in general analyzed with movement. Subject-dependent inversion, however, is not that easy. Some apply movement, but others disagree because you'd need movement on a massive scale, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @JK2  Are you asking me or telling me? Who says it's not that easy?

Comment: By 'easy' I mean there's no controversy. Most grammarians would agree with using movement in subject-auxiliary inversion (Is he happy?), so it's easy to draw a tree diagram. But the other inversion (subject-dependent inversion) is controversial. Please see: https://goo.gl/CPCoiw

Comment: Constituents that are preposed or postposed are labelled as prenucleus and postnucleus respectively. In your example, "under the table" and "lies" would be labelled as prenuclei. I think this is a much better way of analysing it than the ones you're getting over on Lingustics

Comment: You asked for a tree. I've provided one in my answer below. It's easy to understand and follows CGEL's grammar.