# What is the predicate in "Is he happy?"

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis, subjects, subject-verb-inversion

In most theories of grammar, sentences can be broken into smaller chunks called *phrases* and these phrases can be broken into smaller chunks, smaller phrases still. So in the sentence:

- He is happy.

We see two phrases, a noun phrase *he* functioning as Subject, and a verb phrase *is happy* functioning as Predicate:

- [He] [is happy]

I am wondering, however, what the verb phrase/predicate is in the sentence:

- Is he happy?

This sentence does not divide easily into two straightforward chunks.

The plethora of references regarding syntactic (as opposed to semantic) Predicates, and the enormous online literature on verb phrases (VP's) seems to ignore cases where the auxiliary verb has been moved to a position before the Subject.

This is the situation in the example above. In such sentences, what is the structure of the verb phrase, and is the auxiliary verb still part of the verb phrase?

Is there a standard grammar of English which allows for discontinuous verb phrase Predicates?

Comment: This seems very similar to JK2's recent questions [What is the VP in a subject-dependent inversion?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441894) and [Can a VP be defined to include a subject in subject-verb inversion?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27732) (Linguistics SE)

Comment: Why do you say moved? It is simply an interrogative, as opposed to a declarative or imperative or exclamatory sentence, or with those functions....And why do you call it an auxiliary verb? It is only verb. be there is copulative.

Comment: @Lambie: In the context of English, the word "auxiliary" may be defined as referring to [words with certain special properties](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362659/is-there-a-list-of-verbs-for-starting-yes-no-questions/362824#362824), regardless of whether they are used alongside a "main verb" or not.

Comment: @sumelic In that paper on the two be's, he calls what we are discussing: copular inverts. Furthermore, in your own answer you link to auxiliary on Wikipedia which states:"An auxiliary verb (abbreviated aux) is a verb that adds functional or grammatical meaning to the clause in which it appears, such as to express tense, aspect, modality, voice, emphasis, etc. Auxiliary verbs usually accompany a main verb. "  So, not always. Fine. I still would not call it an auxiliary. A copular verb, yes.

Comment: "Be" is always an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the sentence, copular clauses or otherwise.

Comment: Ooh, you do enjoy setting the cat among the pigeons!

Comment: @BillJ's absolutely right, as far as the syntax is concerned. No matter what the construction, _be_ **always** acts like an auxiliary verb. As far as the original question is concerned, nobody ever expects constituent labels to survive transformations. In the transformed question, the node marked VP is reduced to the NP _my friend_; whether you want to prune that VP to an NP is a matter between you and your confessor. And, as for "predicate", I'd say it was _friend_ if I were limited to one word, or `(λx)(Friend (x, me))` if I were allowed logical notation.

Comment: @stoneyB Well, I *always* appreciate a comment from the venerable Stoney. So it seems to be a useful tactic :)

Comment: If all forms of 'be' are auxiliary, then copulas contain a NULL verb.  This is economical because the TAM node can point directly to the complement, without first pointing to a verb.

Comment: Not sure what you were hoping to achieve by asking this question.

Comment: @BillJ Well, partly I wanted to find a good home for your tree diagramm. I was also hoping you might put your comment below your answer in your actual answer. I've been reading around this kind of issue. Most recently [here](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jpb39/pdf/Blevins1994a.pdf)

Comment: @sumelic Similar granted, but not *very* similar! ;) The string *under the table lies* is not discontinuous, and such constructions are not generally assumed to have a gap. Furthermore, there are well documented views on the answer to this question here (for example, see CamGEL, where BillJ got his tree from). The question of consituency in gapped constructions is much discussed in the literature, for example here in Blevins 1994 [Derived constituent order in unbounded dependency constructions](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jpb39/pdf/Blevins1994a.pdf)

Comment: @Lambie The issue of whether *BE* is an auxiliary verb is well established in the literature now. That papers ooooooolllllllldddd.  See  here for why: [Are helper verbs old school?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189)

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, not ***always***! (*Why don't you be more careful / How about you be more careful / If you don't be more careful...* etc)

Comment: I *think* you meant to say: "...sentences can be broken into smaller chunks, called phrases [...] be broken into STILL smaller chunks, AND smaller phrases." But I'm not sure, so I can't fix it.

Comment: OK, many thanks.   But there was a typo still, wasn't there? :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, there were many! Thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps you could also see what kind of answers you get from the experts on Stack Exchange's _Linguistics_ site.

Comment: @BillJ you said *be* was always an auxiliary. Is "being" an auxiliary in "he is being honest"?

Comment: @user178049 Yes, "be" is virtually always an auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is he happy?*

Here is a tree diagram showing how the elements are diagrammed. Note the function label of 'prenucleus' for the verb which is co-indexed to the predicator function represented by 'gap':

[image]

Thus the prenucleus "is" functions as part of predicate consisting of "is happy".

Comment: I think the brain moves the prenucleus to fill the gap (using trust=0 to identify it as a question).   Would you state explicitly that this prenucleus is part of the predicate?  {Trees classify surface structure -- I wish they continued and showed some deeper processing: crossovers, copies, antecedents, and elided determiners}

Comment: Yes, I would say that. If you look carefully, you'll see that I've co-indexed with the _i_ notation the prenucleus to GAP in predicator position in the VP. The predicate is thus "is happy".

Comment: @BillJ +1 Could you put the comment below your post into your post proper (or add in a quote from CamGEL), please?

Comment: Sorry, @Araucaria do you mean AML's comment? The bit about the co-indexing is already in my tree.

Comment: I mean the bit where you say *I would say that [this prenucleus is part of the predicate]* and *The predicate is thus "is happy.* Just so it's nice and explicit :)

Comment: Also, any chance of a reopen vote here, old bean?

Comment: This is good ole Huddleston, right? www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of

> Is he happy?

for grammatical analysis purposes is

> He is happy.

The subject is "He".

The predicate, or full verb phrase, is "is happy".

(Or is this discussion beyond that level of analysis?)

Comment: Yes, kinda. This Q basically assumes that everyone already agrees that "is happy" is the VP in the corresponding declarative :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. A lot of the lingo in this thread is admittedly beyond me, so I got the feeling that it was very likely that I was missing the crux of the debate at all haha.

Comment: The predicate is everything other than the subject.  Inversions don't affect that.  The subject's function is as a pointer to where the predicate will be stored.

Comment: @Araucaria Can you edit your OQ to explicitly say that assumption? It's hard to tell as is.

Comment: @Mitch Now edited.

Answer (score 2):

The, by now, classic, old-fashioned Chomskyan method of analysis here would be that 'is (x) happy' is definitely the VP *and* predicate because it is a simple question-transformation from 'he is happy'. Since that doesn't seem to be convincing to you from the beginning, I attempt to give a non-transformational justification.

The idea of subject and predicate is all about how the elements of a statement map to logical expression. The [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)) is the logical form with a variable and the subject is the instantiation of that variable.

Things like NP and VP are purely [syntactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) (Or as purely syntactic as they can get since the whole point of syntax is to determine what order or construction of elements imply about the semantic relations of those elements as [compositionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) as possible.

Must a logical statement implied by a particular utterance correspond directly to a contiguous sequence of words or phrases? Obviously not. Must a syntactic constituent, a node in a parse tree, correspond to a contiguous sequence? This depends on how you define constituent, but I think it is better to allow non-contiguous segments to be constituents, as that allows easier rules for formation.

These are words to describe parts of *statements*. A question is not a statement. It surely shares a lot with a statement, and in the situation you're describing is a straightforward syntactic transformation of a statement.

All this is to say that for "Is he happy?":

- questions don't have predicates.
- But that is too definitional. Whatever one might say about a question that corresponds to predicate, 'is' and 'happy' somehow together make up that thing corresponding to predicate.
- syntactically, the VP, which happens in this case to correspond to the thing that corresponds to predicate, is 'is (x) happy'.

Whatever all this is, what do you get out of determining for this sentence what the predicate is? I think you get more out of determining what the VP is.

Comment: In most theories of syntax the term *predicate* is the grammatical relations label for the matrix clause VP. In such grammars, what is the VP and what is the predicate are basically the same question. (Though not if one is not using the term *predicate* solely as a grammatical relations label, admittedly.)

Answer (score 1):

The question simply employs a subject-verb inversion. Without the inversion it would be the declarative statement, "he is happy".

In that case, the predicate, stated as an infinitive, is "to be happy".

Comment: Miles off! Think again.

Comment: @BillJ, an explanation trumps an accusation.

Comment: The infinitive is: be happy.